# Return record with max date

Tags: sql, date, max

Table – `Employee.Status.XREF`

```
Client  Employee    Date
198     Jon Doe     3/1/2009
198     Jon Doe     1/1/2009
```

Table – `Employee.Status.History`

```
Client  Employee    Date        Status
198     Jon Doe     5/21/2009   T   
198     Jon Doe     3/1/2009    A
198     Jon Doe     1/1/2009    P
```

Only query records in both `Employee.Status.History` and `Employee.Status.XREF` where `Client`, `Employee`, and `Date` match.

Return only the record from `Employee.Status.History` with the max date (by `client` by `employee`)
In this case it would return

```
Client  Employee    Date        Status
198     Jon Doe     3/1/2009    A
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a sub-select & group by:

```
select b.*  
from Employee.Status.History b,  
( select client, employee, max(date) date  
  from Employee.Status.XREF  
  group by client, employee  
) a  
where b.client = a.client  
and   b.employee = a.employee  
and   b.date = a.date
```

The inner query selects the most recent date.
The outer query returns the entire record on that date for the associated client and employee.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM Employee.Status.History h
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT h.Client, MAX(h.Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM Employee.Status.History h
    INNER JOIN Employee.Status.XREF x ON h.Client = x.Client 
         AND h.Employee = x.Employee AND h.Date = x.Date
) q ON h.Client = q.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql:

```
SELECT b.* FROM tableXREF a, tableSTATUS b
WHERE b.client = a.client
ORDER BY b.Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

MsSql:

```
SELECT TOP(1) b.field1, b.field2 etc. FROM tableXREF a, tableSTATUS b
WHERE b.client = a.client
ORDER BY b.Date DESC
```

I guess ...

Comment: Your solution will only work if there is one user in the database.  The trick is to return records with the maximum history for all users.

Answer (score -1):

why not use a join with a group by clause?

```
select h.client,h.employee,max(h.date),h.Status
from Employee.Status.History h inner join Employee.Status.XREF x on
h.client=x.client and
h.employee=x.employee and
h.date=x.date
group by h.client,h.employee,h.Status
```

Comment: max(h.date) will return the same date for each record returned by the select (the maximum date in the set).  OP is expecting the query to return the joined record with the maximum date.  These two things are very different and hence your query is incorrect.